# android studio preview not displaying? version 1.5.1

Tags: android-studio, preview

I have been using Android Studio quite a lot in recent weeks, and after a short break I decided to start a new project. Before this point, everything was working fine.

My issue is that the preview is not displayed in text or design. If I run an emulator, my project can be seen.

This is a brand new project, I have yet to type a single line of code.

I have uninstalled android studio and reinstalled it, I have rebuilt the project, I have cleaned the project, I have created new projects, I have installed every SDK available to me, I have invalidated caches/restarted.

I've tried multiple themes. I've tried multiple android versions. I've tried multiple devices.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

[Screenshot of design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJGxG.png)

[Screenshot of text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw8xS.png)

**EDIT**

Problem has been fixed by deleting this line of code:

"*tools:shownIn="@layout/activity_main*"

I have never seen this in a project before... Can anyone shed some light onto why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Change the following properties as follows. I just had a similar issue and this solved it for me using visual studio

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

If this proposed solution does answer your question, please select it as the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of this box

Comment: Hi Eminem. 

Thank you for the welcome!

This did not fix my problem, but it did mean that I saw a line of code "tools:shownIn="@layout/activity_main" that I've not seen before. I deleted that, and the preview appeared!

Comment: Glad to have helped you along!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I don't see in my .xml file this line of code. But I changed Theme to Material and that solved my case.

The same problem, but other reasons.

Found info here:
https://www.quora.com/Design-view-is-not-getting-displayed-in-my-Android-Studio-What-should-I-do